# How to check whether a string is substring of another in WhiteSpace?

Tags: string, substring, whitespace-language

I was going through problems on SPOJ, when I saw this [SBStr1](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SBSTR1/). I learnt a little bit of WhiteSpace language, but I could reach only up to loops.
Can anyone please help me on how to check if a string has another string as a substring in WhiteSpace ?

Comment: The strings are binary, so read them bit by bit and convert them into binary numbers, then compare (A/2^n) mod 32 to B, from n from 0 to 4.

Comment: 0 to 4 inclusive ?? And can you explain how it works ?? I know about bit shift (it's possibly the right explanation), please write this in answer part, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to write the Whitespace code for you but here is an approach you can take that easily translates to Whitespace:

```
24 times:
    read 10 bit number into A
    skip space
    read 5 bit number into B
    skip newline

    if (A>>0)%32 == B or (A>>1)%32 == B or ... or (A>>5)%32:
        print 1
    else:
        print 0
    print newline
```

You can implement the bitshifts through repeated division by 2.